# Laravel - Vue: Unknown component footer-div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I started to learn Vue.js based on [this article](https://blog.pusher.com/why-vuejs-laravel/).
The SPA works correctly, but when I want to add a new component I got this error:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

My `vueapp.js`:

```
import Footer from './components/includes/Footer.vue'

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import App from './components/App'
import Welcome from './components/Welcome'
import Page from './components/Page'

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'welcome',
            component: Welcome,
            props: { title: "This is the SPA home" }
        },
        {
            path: '/spa-page',
            name: 'page',
            component: Page,
            props: { 
                title: "This is the SPA Second Page",
                author : {
                    name : "Fisayo Afolayan",
                    role : "Software Engineer",
                    code : "Always keep it clean"
                }
            }
        },    
    ],
})
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { 
        App,
        'footer-div': Footer
    },
    router,
});
```

How to resolve this problem?

**EDIT:**

My folder structure:

[image]

**EDIT2:**

My `App.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'welcome' }" class="nav-link">Home</router-link>
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'page' }" class="nav-link" >Spa-Page</router-link>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </main>
        <footer-div></footer-div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your directory hierarchy down to the folder where `Footer.vue` is present?

Comment: @Rehmat I uploaded a picture about my structure

Comment: Are you using Footer component within the App component? If yes, you need to import it there.

Comment: Yes, I want to include it in the App component. How can I import it in App.vue? And if I import it, it will be imported localy or globaly?

Comment: If you import it in App component, it will be imported locally to that component, but if it is the default layout inherited by all child components, you are good to import it in your App component. Can you please mention your App component's code so I'll answer you precisely.

Comment: I added my App.vue

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't importing the footer component anywhere. You can either import in your main file or in app component. To import it in your App component, modify your code so it looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'welcome' }" class="nav-link">Home</router-link>
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'page' }" class="nav-link" >Spa-Page</router-link>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </main>
        <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Footer from './includes/Footer';
    export default {
        components: {
            Footer
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or if you don't want to modify App component and want to keep it as it is, import Footer component in your **vueapp.js** before importing App component like this:

```
Vue.component('footer-div', require('./components/includes/Footer').default);
```